# How can I target a particular path/ page in an ionic app for android using onesignal push notification

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, onesignal

I just built an ecommerce app using ionic and wooCommerce as the backend. i send Push notifications with [OneSignal](http://onesignal.com) and it's been excellent so far. What i would like to do is this:

**How can I target a particular path/ page in an ionic app for android using Onesignal when the notification is tapped**

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

When using OneSignal with Ionic, to direct users to a specific location in your app, make sure to send all the relevant information as part of the additional data and handle launching the relevant page within the [handleNotificationOpened event](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ionic-sdk#section--handlenotificationopened-).